# Batch echo command issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

It is inside the 2 pauses. I cannot understand why it is not working. Do mind the rest. It is a part of TGBF. As far as I can tell the text after the echo is an error, but I don't know why? Does it lie in how many bits the operating system is? It's 64 as it is now.
I did copy and paste it in, but I doubt that would effect it.

```
@echo off
Title Epidsode one Season one 
Echo Early Alpha 0.01
Echo CLOSED FOR TESTING CFT
Pause
Echo  0  \0/ |0__ \0          __0   0/  0/ __0|
Echo /|\  |   |    |\          /|   |  /|    |
Echo / \ / \ / \  / \          / \ / \ / \  / \
Pause
Echo Warming up assests Step 1
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
Echo Warming up assets Step 2
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
Echo Warming up assets final stelp
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 200>nul
Pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe operator | is a special character and can not be ECHOed as is. You need to escape it with ^.

Here's the correct script

```
@echo off
Title Epidsode one Season one 
Echo Early Alpha 0.01
Echo CLOSED FOR TESTING CFT
Pause
Echo  0  \0/ ^|0__ \0          __0   0/  0/ __0^|
Echo /^|\  ^|   ^|    ^|\          /^|   ^|  /^|    ^|
Echo / \ / \ / \  / \          / \ / \ / \  / \
Pause
Echo Warming up assests Step 1
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
Echo Warming up assets Step 2
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 700>nul
Echo Warming up assets final stelp
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 200>nul
Pause
```